# Java swing: labels and fields apper only after resizing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to create a simple Java Swing app with few buttons and text fields. However after I launch my program all I see is an empty window. All elements appear only when I manualy change the size of the window. How can I change that and make all elements appear immediately?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

class JavaLesson extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new JavaLesson();
    }

    public JavaLesson(){
        this.setSize(400,400);

        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();
        int xPos = (dim.width / 2) - (this.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (dim.height / 2) - (this.getHeight() / 2);

        this.setLocation(xPos,yPos);


        this.setTitle("My app");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("This is label");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Send");
        JTextField textField1  = new JTextField("Type here",7);

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(textField1);

        this.add(panel);

        textField1.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to invoke `setVisible(true)` AFTER the components have been added to the frame. You can use `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` to center the frame. Invoke this method just before the setVisible(). Swing components should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. See the `FrameDemo.java` demo code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for the better way to structure your code using all the above suggestions.

Comment: Well, did the suggestion help?? If it did, its nice to let people know. If not, then maybe others will answer to give other suggestion. You should be responding to all questions to keep the forum informed on the status of your question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your this.setVisible(true) on the line after you added your panel to your frame, doing so, it will display all the components you've added in the frame.

Try this and see if it works out.

```
 public JavaLesson(){
    this.setSize(400,400);
    ..
    ..  

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("This is label");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Send");
    JTextField textField1  = new JTextField("Type here",7);

    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(textField1);

    this.add(panel);   
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Hope this helps. 
Cheers :)